# New URL on django admin independent of the apps

Tags: django, django-admin, python-2.7, django-urls, django-1.4

I am using django 1.4 and Python 2.7.

I just have a simple requirement where I have to add a new URL to the django admin app. I know how to add URLs which are for the custom apps but am unable figure out how to add URLs which are of the admin app. Please guide me through this.

Basically the full URL should be something like `admin/my_url`.

**UPDATE**

I want a way after which I can as well reverse map the URL using admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for Jingo's answer to your original question. With your clarifying comment to the answer in mind:
Such a URL is *not* "independent of the apps", it is a URL for the app "admin".

Adding a URL to the admin site is similar to ModelAdmin, by overriding get_urls():
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites

EDIT:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite

is an admin site, by default "the" admin site is instantiated as "django.contrib.admin.site" (and then e.g. your ModelAdmin's are registered against that). So you can subclass AdminSite for your own MyAdminSite and re-define get_urls() there:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_urls():
        ...


...
my_admin_site = MyAdminSite()
...
my_admin_site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Make sure you use my_admin_site in urls.py instead now:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf

Regarding the actual contents of get_urls(),see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls
(of course calling super() of MyAdminSite). Also note the convenient "admin_view" wrapper mentioned there.

P.S.: In theory, you could also just define get_urls() and then monkeypatch the default admin site so that it uses your get_urls() but I don't know if that would actually work - you'd probably have to monkeypatch right after its "first" import...

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong use of words. I actually wanted this. But, could you please give a brief on what steps are involved to do this? Or an example where this has been done?

Answer (score 4):

Just put your desired url mapping before the admin mapping in your root urls.py. The first match for the request will be taken, because django goes the url mappings from top to down. Just remember that you don't use an url the admin normally needs or provides because this will never match with a custom mapping in front of it. HTH!

Comment: That is a possible solution. But, it doesn't register the URL as an admin URL (like that in case of model URLs). This is another URL of my site that I define and serve it before Django's own URLs. I want a way after which I can as well reverse map the URL using admin.